# How do I get the "Fasting" title in the Fire Starter stage of Half Minute Hero?

Tags: achievements, half-minute-hero

Now I'm stuck on the "Fasting" title, in quest 05 (Fire Starter) of Half Minute Hero. I have absolutely no clue what to do here. I've tried completing the stage as quickly as possible, before the fire can even begin to start, yet nothing seems to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fasting refers to food, not speed. To get the Fasting title, simply complete the quest without eating food from a vendor (Healing Herbs don't count).

Comment: I thought it would be a pun. :(